# Left merge on list of dictionaries not working

Tags: python

As an exercise, I wanted to be less reliant on pandas and build a custom merge function on a list of dictionaries. Essentially, this is a left merge, where the original list is preserved and if the key has multiple matches then extra rows are added. However in my case, the extra rows appear to be added but with the exact same information.

Could anyone steer me in the right direction, as to where this code is going wrong?

```
def merge(self, l2, key):
    #self.data is a list of dictionaries
    #l2 is the second list of dictionaries to merge
    headers = l2[0]
    found = {}

    append_list = []
    for row in self.data:
        for row_b in l2:
            if row_b[key] == row[key] and row[key] not in found:
                found[row[key]] = ""
                for header in headers:
                    row[header] = row_b[header]
            elif row_b[key] == row[key]:
                new_row = row
                for header in headers:
                    new_row[header] = row_b[header]
                    append_list.append(new_row)


    self.data.extend(append_list)
```

**Edit:** Here is some sample input, and expected output:

```
self.data = [{'Name':'James', 'Country':'Australia'}, {'Name':'Tom', 'Country':'France'}]

l2 = [{'Country':'France', 'Food':'Frog Legs'}, {'Country':'Australia', 'Food':'Meat Pie'},{'Country':'Australia', 'Food':'Pavlova'}]
```

I would expect self.data to equal the following after passing through the function, with a parameter of 'Country':

```
[{'Name':'James', 'Country':'Australia', 'Food':'Meat Pie'}, {'Name':'James', 'Country':'Australia', 'Food':'Pavlova'}, {'Name':'Tom', 'Country':'France', 'Food':'Frog Legs'}]
```

Comment: Could you show a sample input and output and explain what you wanted to get instead please?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Sure, I edited my question.

Comment: Isn't that last entry missing the food?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Apologies, typing faster than I can think. Yes, you're correct and I've edited.

Comment: `'Name'` is only defined on the left side of your join…did you mean `'Country'` as the join property?

Comment: @dtanabe Would you believe I made another mistake haha? Edited again. Okay, this is the final version. Appreciate any help you can give on my code.

Comment: What is the purpose of `headers = l2[0]` ? The first element of your list `l2` doesn't look like a "header row".

Comment: It's fixed. Assume it as `list(l2[0].keys())`

Answer (score 0):

The function below takes two lists of dictionaries, where the dictionaries are expected to all have `keyprop` as one of their properties:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import product

def left_join(left_table, right_table, keyprop):
    # create a dictionary indexed by `keyprop` on the left
    left = defaultdict(list)
    for row in left_table:
        left[row[keyprop]].append(row)

    # create a dictionary indexed by `keyprop` on the right
    right = defaultdict(list)
    for row in right_table:
        right[row[keyprop]].append(row)

    # now simply iterate through the "left side",
    # grabbing rows from the "right side" if they are available
    result = []
    for key, left_rows in left.items():
        right_rows = right.get(key)
        if right_rows:
            for left_row, right_row in product(left_rows, right_rows):
                result.append({**left_row, **right_row})
        else:
            result.extend(left_rows)

    return result

    sample1 = [{'Name':'James', 'Country':'Australia'}, {'Name':'Tom', 'Country':'France'}]
    sample2 = [{'Country':'France', 'Food':'Frog Legs'}, {'Country':'Australia', 'Food':'Meat Pie'},{'Country':'Australia', 'Food':'Pavlova'}]
    print(left_join(sample1, sample2, 'Country'))
    # outputs:
    # [{'Name': 'James', 'Country': 'Australia', 'Food': 'Meat Pie'},
    #  {'Name': 'James', 'Country': 'Australia', 'Food': 'Pavlova'},
    #  {'Name': 'Tom', 'Country': 'France', 'Food': 'Frog Legs'}]
```

In a data set where you can assume that rows are unique on the value of `keyprop` in their respective data sets, the implementation is quite a bit simpler:

```
def left_join(left_table, right_table, keyprop):
    # create a dictionary indexed by `keyprop` on the left
    left = {row[keyprop]: row for row in left_table}

    # create a dictionary indexed by `keyprop` on the right
    right = {row[keyprop]: row for row in right_table}

    # now simply iterate through the "left side",
    # grabbing rows from the "right side" if they are available
    return [{**leftrow, **right.get(key, {})} for key, leftrow in left.items()]
```